# Error: Task 'proguardRelease' not found in root project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Any ideas? Just updated Android Studio and the associated build tools and it's broken gradle / proGuard. With my previous config in place, with a **minifyEnabled true**, it refuses to play with a:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'getDefaultProguardFile'
```

If I comment out the minifyEnabled and proguardFiles entries I instead get a:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'proguardRelease' not found in root project 'testApp'.
```

Where the apps build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'foo.bar.testApp'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 7
        versionName '0.5.0 - Alpha test'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile project(':androidsvg')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.1'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.0'
}
```

With the projects build.gradle file being:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And form the logs, the error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method proguardFile() for arguments [/usr/local/opt/Android_sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt, proguard-rules.pro] on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, applicationIdSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=null, minifyEnabled=true, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at build_6k5pyml806li01s692ttf90ka$_run_closure1_closure5_closure7.doCall(/Users/arober11/AndroidStudioProjects/testApp/app/build.gradle:20)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:324)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:62)
    at build_6k5pyml806li01s692ttf90ka$_run_closure1_closure5.doCall(/Users/arober11/AndroidStudioProjects/testApp/app/build.gradle:18)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.Action$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.buildTypes(BaseExtension.groovy:248)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.buildTypes(Unknown Source)
    at build_6k5pyml806li01s692ttf90ka$_run_closure1.doCall(/Users/arober11/AndroidStudioProjects/testApp/app/build.gradle:17)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at build_6k5pyml806li01s692ttf90ka.run(/Users/arober11/AndroidStudioProjects/testApp/app/build.gradle:3)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 43 more
2015-01-16 14:28:22,654 [244566952]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Gradle DSL method not found: 'proguardFile()' 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.LocationAwareExternalSystemException: Gradle DSL method not found: 'proguardFile()'
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

The file is there and accessible e.g.

```
ls /usr/local/opt/Android_sdk/tools/proguard/
README              examples            proguard-android.txt
ant             lib             proguard-project.txt
bin             license.html
docs                proguard-android-optimize.txt
```

Comment: there is no more proguard in android studio, you use the `minify`

Comment: Uhm yes there is. `minifyEnabled` replaces `runProguard`, but the line         `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` is still needed.

Comment: try a diff version of build tools in build.gradle??  "21.0.2"

Comment: My app also uses 21.1.2 and doesn't have these issues, so I don't think that's going to solve anything. It does say "21.1.2" instead of '21.1.2', so with double quotes, though, although I don't think that matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

You have got `proguardFile` instead of `proguardFiles`, so just add the -s to the end and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, the 's' got lost in the cut'n'paste here, still broke :(

Comment: Do  you have `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` in your gradle-wrapper.properties file? Android Studio should do this automatically, but it can hurt to check.

Comment: "can't hurt", linux is messing with my '-key again >.<

Comment: Yes: `#Thu Dec 04 01:26:24 GMT 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
`

Answer (score -1):

Your dolution should be     `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'`

Comment: Nope: that doesn't touch the issue of:  Task 'proguardRelease' not found in root project 'testApp'.